# How can I connect to Watson Speech to Text server using C++ Rest SDK Websocket

Tags: c++, websocket, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I'm trying to connect to Watson Speech to Text server uisng websocket but when I try to make the connection don't connect. I get the connection token to autenticate my websocket connection, so concatenate with the URL and try to connect but as I sayd befire don't connect, could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

This is my code now:

```
#include <cpprest/ws_client.h>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace web;
using namespace web::websockets;
using namespace web::websockets::client;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;

#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>


using namespace utility; // Common utilities like string conversions
using namespace web;                        // Common features like URIs.
using namespace web::http;                  // Common HTTP functionality
using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features
using namespace concurrency::streams;       // Asynchronous streams

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();
  // Open stream to output file.
  pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("../data/token.txt")).then([=](ostream outFile)
  {
     *fileStream = outFile;

     // Create http_client to send the request.
     http_client_config config;

     // Build request URI and start the request.
    credentials cred(L"******-****-****-****-************", L"************");
    config.set_credentials(cred);
    http_client client(U("https://stream.watsonplatform.net"), config);

    uri_builder builder(U("/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"));
    return client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string());
})    

    // Handle response headers arriving.
    .then([=](http_response response)
 {
    //printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());

    // Write response body into the file.
    return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
 })

// Close the file stream.
    .then([=](size_t)
{
    return fileStream->close();
});

// Wait for all the outstanding I/O to complete and handle any exceptions
try
{
    requestTask.wait();
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
    printf("Error exception:%s\n", e.what());
}

//Ler arquivo e guardar token//////
std::ifstream file;
std::string token;

file.open("../data/token.txt");
file >> token;


std::string  url = "wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?watson-token=" + token + "&model=pt-BR_BroadbandModel";
uri wsUrl(conversions::to_string_t(url));

websocket_client wsclient;

wsclient.connect(wsUrl).wait();


}
```